# Added paths in MATLAB seems not to be added

Tags: matlab, path

I run the main code that needs some subcodes in specific folders that are located within the working directory. I add these folders with the following commands:

```
addpath('./k_means');
addpath('./pb');
```

The error message when the main file (in the current working directory) tries to read subcodes in the above directories.

> Undefined function or variable 'demo_pb'.

What's the fix for that?

Comment: You can use `mfilename('fullpath')` to get the current folder of the currently running script. From those path create the fullpath of your two subfolder.

Comment: @obchardon, all folders are located in the currently running code directory and the current directory that is obtained with "cd" command is as the same with the currently running code .

Comment: Using the fullpath is, IMO, safer. With the few information provided, it's hard to help you more. Where is the `demo_pb` function stored ? And how do you call those function ?

Comment: @obchardon, "demo_pb" is stored in the "pb" folder and it is called as follows:       pb_im=demo_pb(input_im);

Comment: For debugging the problem: **1.** Remove the `addpath('./pb');`. **2.** Before `pb_im=demo_pb(input_im);`, replace it with the command: `cd('./pb');`. **3.** Place a breakpoint at the `cd('./pb');` line and execute code until stop at breakpoint. **4.** Single step (press F10). **5.** Verify the current folder is `pb` and the file `demo_pb.m` is in the folder. **6.** Step into `demo_pb` (press F11), and see if it works.